# Gtk# TreeView keep a row selected

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a GTK Sharp *TreeView* and I want to be able to make a row "sticky" i.e. to always remain selected. What is the best way to do this?

Currently I have an `IsSticky` variable on the model and, after a selection change, I go through the TreeView's Store and re-select all the items that are sticky. This causes the GUI to flash and I imagine there is a better way to do this?